# How to sort facetted ggplot by x-axis in geom_bar() with identity

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```r
dat <- structure(list(type = c("exon", "intron", "exon", 
"intron", "exon", "intron", "exon", "intron", 
"exon", "intron", "exon", "intron", "exon", 
"intron", "exon", "intron", "exon", "intron", 
"exon", "intron"), nfn = c("dy1_PLT4.x4_01", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_01", "dy1_PLT4.x4_02", "dy1_PLT4.x4_02", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_03", "dy1_PLT4.x4_03", "dy1_PLT4.x4_01", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_01", "dy1_PLT4.x4_02", "dy1_PLT4.x4_02", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_03", "dy1_PLT4.x4_03", "dy1_PLT4.x4_04", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_04", "dy1_PLT4.x4_05", "dy1_PLT4.x4_05", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_06", "dy1_PLT4.x4_06", "dy1_PLT4.x4_07", 
"dy1_PLT4.x4_07"), perc = c(0.276422764227642, 0.723577235772358, 
0.328301886792453, 0.671698113207547, 0.387096774193548, 0.612903225806452, 
0.739130434782609, 0.260869565217391, 0.367965367965368, 0.632034632034632, 
0.287749287749288, 0.712250712250712, 0.373170731707317, 0.626829268292683, 
0.404320987654321, 0.595679012345679, 0.4625, 0.5375, 0.311418685121107, 
0.688581314878893), celltype = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V")), .Names = c("type", "nfn", "perc", "celltype"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat
#>      type            nfn      perc celltype
#> 1    exon dy1_PLT4.x4_01 0.2764228        F
#> 2  intron dy1_PLT4.x4_01 0.7235772        F
#> 3    exon dy1_PLT4.x4_02 0.3283019        F
#> 4  intron dy1_PLT4.x4_02 0.6716981        F
#> 5    exon dy1_PLT4.x4_03 0.3870968        F
#> 6  intron dy1_PLT4.x4_03 0.6129032        F
#> 7    exon dy1_PLT4.x4_01 0.7391304        V
#> 8  intron dy1_PLT4.x4_01 0.2608696        V
#> 9    exon dy1_PLT4.x4_02 0.3679654        V
#> 10 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_02 0.6320346        V
#> 11   exon dy1_PLT4.x4_03 0.2877493        V
#> 12 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_03 0.7122507        V
#> 13   exon dy1_PLT4.x4_04 0.3731707        V
#> 14 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_04 0.6268293        V
#> 15   exon dy1_PLT4.x4_05 0.4043210        V
#> 16 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_05 0.5956790        V
#> 17   exon dy1_PLT4.x4_06 0.4625000        V
#> 18 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_06 0.5375000        V
#> 19   exon dy1_PLT4.x4_07 0.3114187        V
#> 20 intron dy1_PLT4.x4_07 0.6885813        V
```

With the following code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = nfn, y = perc, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1,size=5)) +
  facet_wrap(~celltype, scales = "free") + 
  xlab("")
```

I can make the following image:

[image]

What I want to do is to sort the x-axis for each "F" and "V" facet by the intron percentage in increasing order. How can I achieve that?

For example, the x-axis in "F" panel would be ordered into:

```r
dy1_PLT4.x4_03, dy1_PLT4.x4_02, dy1_PLT4.x4_01
```

And "V" panel would be ordered into:

```r
dy1_PLT4.x4_01, dy1_PLT4.x4_06, dy1_PLT4.x4_05,
dy1_PLT4.x4_04, dy1_PLT4.x4_02, ... dy1_PLT4.x4_03
```

Answer (score 2):

This gets a bit tricky, but if we label the different facets differently, then when we plot change the display labels, you can get what you want. The trick is to make sure the labels you manually add to the plot are in the same order as they appear on the plot. I do that with the below.

```
#Sort the data by percentage (within each facet) and cell type (between each facet)
sorteddat <- dat[order(dat$perc),]
sorteddat <- sorteddat[order(sorteddat$celltype),]

#Keep only introns for level ordering
reduceddat <- sorteddat[sorteddat$type == "intron",]

#Remember, the label names, we'll need this soon
oldLabels <- unique(reduceddat$nfn)

#Change the labels for F types to something else so we can distinguish them as unique factors
reduceddat$nfn <- as.character(reduceddat$nfn)
reduceddat$nfn[reduceddat$celltype == "F"] <-paste0(reduceddat$nfn[reduceddat$celltype == "F"] ,"_F")
reduceddat$nfn <- factor(reduceddat$nfn)

#We need to do this in the sorted data too, since this is what we'll plot
sorteddat$nfn <- as.character(sorteddat$nfn)
sorteddat$nfn[sorteddat$celltype == "F"] <-paste0(sorteddat$nfn[sorteddat$celltype == "F"] ,"_F")
sorteddat$nfn <- factor(sorteddat$nfn)

#Relevel the nfn variable based on the sorted dataframe
sorteddat$nfn <- factor(sorteddat$nfn, levels = unique(reduceddat$nfn))

#Plot with the addition of the manual labels we stored earlier.
ggplot(sorteddat, aes(x = nfn, y = perc, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1,size=5)) +
  facet_wrap(~celltype, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = oldLabels) +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to split the data frame into two separate data frames by `celltype`, plot each one separately and then lay them out together as if they had been faceted. Then the factor levels can be set separately for each level of `celltype`.

Below is an example. I've also changed the x-axis labeling. Since all but the final numeric identifiers of each `nfn` value are the same, you can remove the repeated text, just plot the numbers as the tick labels, and use `dy1_PLT4.x4` as the x-axis title, making the plot easier to read.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(egg)
library(grid)

# Split data by celltype and create two plot, stored in a list
p = map(split(dat %>% arrange(celltype, perc), dat$celltype), 
        ~ggplot(.x %>% mutate(nfn=gsub(".*(.{2}$)", "\\1", nfn),
                              nfn=factor(nfn, levels=nfn[type=="intron"])), 
                 aes(x = nfn, y = perc, fill = type)) +
          geom_col() +
          scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
          theme_minimal() +
          theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
          facet_grid(~celltype) + 
          labs(y="Percent") 
       )

# Remove y labels and ticks from right plot
p[[2]] = p[[2]] + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                        axis.title.y=element_blank())

# Remove legend from left plot
p[[1]] = p[[1]] + guides(fill=FALSE)

# Lay out the two plots
ggarrange(plots=p, ncol=2, widths=c(3,7), 
          bottom=textGrob(gsub("(.*).{3}$", "\\1", dat$nfn[1]), gp=gpar(fontsize=10)))
```

[image]

Another option is to plot only the intron percent, since the exon percent is always 100 - intron-percent. If we do that, we can take advantage of the `reorder_within` and `scale_x_reordered` functions in the `drlib` package (this is a "personal" package that may change at any time, so it might be best to make your own copies of these functions if you want to use them regularly). This also has the advantage of using a lot less ink to present the data.

```
#devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/drlib")
library(drlib)

ggplot(dat %>% filter(type=="intron") %>% 
         mutate(nfn=gsub(".*(.{2}$)", "\\1", nfn)), 
       aes(reorder_within(nfn, perc, celltype), perc)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", perc*100)), size=3.5) +
  facet_grid(.~celltype, scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels=percent, expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour="grey50", fill=NA)) +
  labs(x=gsub("(.*).{3}$", "\\1", dat$nfn[1]), y="Percent Intron")
```

[image]